# permutation for pd.Series cause inplace change

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know the difference between `np.random.permutation` and `np.random.shuffle`.

But when I using the `np.random.permutation` for `pd.Series`, it will accidentally cause the series in place change and also cause the dataframe in place change.

I know how to permutation it in another way, but I want to **know if this design problem for `numpy` or `pandas`?**

demo data show:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
t = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
#np.random.permutation(t)
assert all(t == np.random.permutation(t))
```

It will not raise `AssertionError`.
It will output a shuffled array. But when you check the `t`, it also changes.

If you use `np.array` or `list`, it will be ok.

```
t = np.array([1,2,3,4])
np.random.permutation(t)
assert all(t == np.random.permutation(t))
```

It do will raise `AssertionError`.

Comment: Did you just happen to get 'lucky' in the first case, in which the permuted `Series` was identical to the original `Series`? With only 4 values this isn't that unlikely. I receive an `AssertionError` for your first code.

Comment: The first code yields Assertion Error

Comment: That `assert` is not the essential part of the question.  The question is about why `t` is permuted in-place.  I seem to recall someone asking the same question within the last few weeks.  Does anyone else recall such a question?

Comment: Found it.  It was a numpy issue, not a stackoverflow question: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [bug in numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11975).  For some array-like objects, [`numpy.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) shuffles its argument in-place.  According to the docstring, it is supposed to return a shuffled copy of the input; it should not change the input in-place.

As you noted in the question, you can avoid the problem by passing in an actual numpy array.  If `t` is a Pandas `Series`, you could use `np.random.permutation(t.values)`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a loop to check the assert function, and I used .any() to replace "all".

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(100):
    t = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    assert (t != np.random.permutation(t)).any(), print('Assertion at', i)
```

The outputs showed assertion happening randomly.